# Sequelize Migration Remove Primary Key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was reading through the sequelize documentation, and I was unsure whether there was a way to remove a primary key constraint on a column.

Here is the most relevant link:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/#changecolumntablename-attributename-datatypeoroptions-options

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was dropping to sql, not sure if I was doing something wrong but nothing else I tried seemed to work.

From: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/313

```
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query('ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY');
}
```

Comment: Note: This is for MySql only

Answer (score 0):

yes, use changeColumn and provide a complete new column definition (same as original), but without the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeConstraint('myTable', 'myTable_pkey'); // myTable_pkey = name of constraint
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addConstraint('myTable', {
      fields: ['id'],
      type: 'primary key',
      name: 'myTable_pkey'
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code will remove primary key for the table:

```
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.removeConstraint('table_name', 'PRIMARY');
}
```

and this removes the constraints like foreign key:

```
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.removeConstraint('table_name', 'constraint_name');
}
```